# insert script for 'Image' type data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i am getting the problem to generate the 'insert into' script for table.table having the column Photo an which is of 'Image' type.

how i can generate the insert script for it.

(i am trying with MyGeneration tool to generate insert script but it fails to generate)

is there any way or tool to generate insert script.

thanks in advance

Comment: First off: don't use `IMAGE` anymore. It's been deprecated with SQL Server 2005. Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert image to byte[] to insert it into database

Here is [Storing and Retrieving Images from SQL Server using Microsoft .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImageSaveInDataBase.aspx) article, which will be helpful for your task.